# What is WooCommerce save_post action?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to use save_post action in my WordPress, test this actions, but that not work:

```
add_action('save_post', 'run_when_product_saved');
add_action('save_post_product', 'run_when_product_saved');
```

What is the correct save_post action for WooCommerce?

Comment: Are you trying to add action when the product is created or updated?

Comment: Yes Exactly, I want run "run_when_product_saved" on post saveing.

Comment: Try using this hook, it's after 3.X woocommerce woocommerce_update_product